# Microsoft Graph API Synchronisation API, update secret token only works at second call

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm implementing (in Python with the Microsoft Graph API) the creation of Azure AD application based on the AWS template. I'm stuck when implementing the automatic role provisioning like describe in this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/application-provisioning-configure-api?tabs=http#step-3-authorize-access

When I call the `servicePrincipals/{id}/synchronization/secrets` API **for the first time just after the creation of the synchronization job**, I receive a HTTP error (400 - Bad Request) with the following body :

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The credentials could not be saved. This is due to an internal storage issue in the Microsoft Azure AD service. For information on how to address this issue, please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=867915",
    "innerError": {
      "code": "CredentialStorageBadRequest",
      "details": [],
      "message": "The credentials could not be saved. This is due to an internal storage issue in the Microsoft Azure AD service. For information on how to address this issue, please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=867915",
      "target": null,
      "innerError": {
        "code": "CredentialStorageBadRequest",
        "details": [],
        "message": "Message:The credentials could not be saved. This is due to an internal storage issue in the Microsoft Azure AD service. For information on how to address this issue, please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=867915",
        "target": null
      },
      "date": "2021-01-05T15:53:59",
      "request-id": "---",
      "client-request-id": "---"
    }
  }
}
```

When a do a second same call (with MS Graph Explorer, Postman or directly in Python), it works, the second call returns an HTTP 204 like expected ! So I think my request is correct.

This is my implementation (which works because I retry the call a second time…) :

```py
# Default value :
GRAPH_API_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{endpoint}"

class Azure:
  # […]

  # self._http_headers contains my token to access to MS Graph API
  # self._aws_key_id and self._aws_access_key contains AWS credentials

  def _save_sync_job_auth(self, principal_id):
    self._put(
        f"servicePrincipals/{principal_id}/synchronization/secrets",
        {"value": [
            {"key": "ClientSecret", "value": self._aws_key_id},
            {"key": "SecretToken", "value": self._aws_access_key},
        ]},
        retry=1  # If I put 0 here, my script fail
    )

  # […]
  
  def _put(self, endpoint, json, retry=0):
    return self._http_request(requests.put, endpoint, retry, json=json)

  # […]

  def _http_request(self, func, endpoint, retry=0, **kwargs):
    url = GRAPH_API_URL.format(endpoint=endpoint)
    response = func(url, headers=self._http_headers, **kwargs)

    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        if retry:
            logging.warning(f"Error when calling {func.__name__.upper()} {url}")
            return self._http_request(func, endpoint, retry - 1, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise e

    return response
```

Am I missing something ? Have you a solution to remove this "retry hack" ?

Comment: Does the step [Test the connection to the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-provisioning-configure-api?tabs=http#test-the-connection-to-the-application) work for the first time?

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention it in my post, but the `validateCredentials` API is called just before my `_save_sync_job_auth ` method and the HTTP request returns 204

Comment: Just to isolate the above issue outside of the code, i would suggest you to try the same Graph API/payload in Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see still you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: Yes I reproduce the issue when calling directly the API from MS Graph Explorer. The same thing happen, the first call failed and the second call is ok.

Comment: oh wow thats strange. I would suggest you to see if you can check with their support and see why you see this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I don't use this API anymore. I use the azuread_application_app_role Terraform resource instead to provision some roles, so it will be harder for me to test.

Comment: hmm, interesting... so you can check from that end you can anything related like the above.

Comment: Thanks to this post I can confirm this still a known bug. I've observed the API failing 3 times in a row with an interval of 10 seconds between calls.